# Failed to fetch Sources and Packages, getting 404

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS prior to doing release upgrade. Unfortunately, it's not working. APT is claiming that `Sources` do not exist at [lv archive repo](http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/), which clearly is not true:

```
$ curl -I http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources.gz
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 10:37:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 22:49:07 GMT
ETag: "8bd598-5f322e-4be88adc45ec0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 6238766
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-gzip

$ curl -I http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources.bz2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 10:37:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 22:49:07 GMT
ETag: "8bf600-4c95e1-4be88adc45ec0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5019105
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-bzip2
```

`apt-get update` log below.

```
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://repo.percona.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://repo.percona.com precise Release
Hit http://repo.percona.com precise/main Sources
Hit https://get.docker.io docker Release.gpg
Hit https://get.docker.io docker Release
Hit http://repo.percona.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://repo.percona.com precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://repo.percona.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit https://get.docker.io docker/main amd64 Packages
Hit https://get.docker.io docker/main i386 Packages
Get:1 https://get.docker.io docker/main TranslationIndex [77.0 kB]
Ign https://get.docker.io docker/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://repo.percona.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.percona.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign https://get.docker.io docker/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://get.docker.io docker/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

*Resolved*

Apparently it's a problem with lv.archive.ubuntu.com. Removing "lv" prefix (and moving to archive.ubuntu.com) resolved the issue.

Comment: Have you tried with different server ?

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked, though there is no obvious difference when comparing lv.archive.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com... I'll edit my post appropriately.

Comment: @KasparsFoigts please, post an answer instead of editing your question to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is resolved by changing apt-get repository host from `lv.archive.ubuntu.com` to `archive.ubuntu.com`. Apparrently mirror is not up to date or has some configuration issues.

Comment: how to change repository host?